# Responsive round inside border-bottom effect for a div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rounding, border-box

Trying to achieve similar effect on this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aixLl.jpg
Rounded edges for the inner border of the div. Is it possible to do it with CSS? Div suppose to be full with responsive so it is best to have some border effect that can be smaller or bigger depending on the size of the div.

```css
.image-container
{
border-bottom:#000 30px solid;
border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
border-bottom: 50px solid;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container image-container">
  
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/uqXZmk4.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can point you in the right direction, Since I think the original picture is made in Photoshop...

Try adding this to the image selector in CSS. You can tweak the PX depending on how you want it.

**CSS:**

```
.image-container {
    background-color:black; }

.img-responsive{  width:100%;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50px; }
```

See: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za219gm6/)

Comment: used 10% instead of 50px worked great. Thanks for the answer.